# Rate of convergence for series.

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, numerical-methods

1)What is convergence rate of a series
\begin{equation}
   K(k)
 =    {\frac{\pi}{2}} \hspace{1mm} {\sum_{m=0}^\infty}\binom{-1/2}{m}^2 k^{2m}
\end{equation}
Note that the presence of squares of binomial coefficients makes the convergence
worse, leading to monotone and very slow convergence for $k \simeq 1$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The binomial coefficient asymptotic is $\binom{-\frac12}{m} \sim \cos(m \pi) \sqrt{\frac1{\pi m}}.$ So your general term is asymptotic to $\frac{\cos^2(m \pi)}{m \pi} k^{2m},$ which, by @robjohn's trenchant observation, equals $\frac{k^{2m}}{m \pi}.$

Comment: And $\cos^2(m\pi)$ is... :-)

Comment: For integer $m$,
$$
\binom{m-1/2}{m}=(-1)^m\frac1{4^m}\binom{2m}{m}\sim\frac{(-1)^m}{\sqrt{\pi m}}
$$
so
$$
\frac\pi2\binom{m-1/2}{m}^2k^{2m}\sim\frac{k^{2m}}{2m}
$$
so the series diverges at $k=1$.

Comment: @robjohn you taunt me cruelly... :)

Comment: Thanks. So I can conclude by saying that the series is $O(1/m)$?

Comment: @Mark: only if $k=1$ (i.e. it diverges). If $k\lt1$, then the series is $O(k^{2m})$ or even $o(k^{2m})$.

Comment: Excuse me, but there was a second part of question. Can I edit my question, inserting a new point?

Comment: @Mark no one is stopping you :)